# Google sheets : Conditional formatting on date column with "T" in it. eg: "2020-03-21T15:17:47.000Z"

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to do conditional formatting on a date column which contains date value as "2020-03-21T15:17:47.000Z". i.e with a "T" in it.

The conditional formatting (for 'date' < 03/31/2020') does not recognise this date.

I tried to do TO_DATE() on this column, but it gives the same output and doesn't recognise in conditional formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this custom formula as a conditional formatting rule:

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,FIND("T",A1)-1)) < DATEVALUE("03/31/2020")
```

[image: illustration]

Answer (score 2):

You can also use

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(P1,"(.*)T")+0>DATEVALUE("3/20/2020")
```

[image]